# Changing an FSharpList in C#

Tags: c#, f#, c#-to-f#

```
FSharpList<FSharpList<int>> newImageList;
FSharpList<int> row;
for(int i = 0; i < CurrentImage.Header.Height)
{
    row = PPMImageLibrary.GrayscaleImage(CurrentImage.ImageListData);
    newImageList.Head = row;
}
```

Above I'm trying to take a int list list and set each index to row which is a int list. Obviously I can't do it with `.Head`, and if I could it would only change the first index. I'm wondering how I could possibly make this work, I'm having a hard time getting any index of newImageList in the first place.

Comment: like any Collection I am sure that there is a Collection.Add method you are just assigning newImage.Head where I believe that you should be adding that particular row or row index to the newImageList collection.. but I don't know FSharp

Comment: `FSharpList` instances are immutable, therefore you cannot change them. If you do want to change the list you'll have to construct a new list based on the existing one, with the elements modified as appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FSharpList is an immutable list. Therefore you cannot assign its Head and Tail properties something. However, you can try adding your FSharp list into a generic C# List or any collection that inherits an IEnumerable. For example from your code:

```
List<int> newImageList = new List<int>();

for(int i = 0; i < CurrentImage.Header.Height)
{
   newImageList.AddRange(PPMImageLibrary.GrayscaleImage(CurrentImage.ImageListData)); // I am assuming your GrayscaleImage method might return multiple records.

}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think that extension method is necessary. F# lists already implement IEnumerable, so a straight-up C# cast is really all you need.

Comment: @JoelMueller you are right. I just check the inheritance of FSharpList and it is inheriting IEnumerable. Thanks for the warning.